# Creating Button According to Search Through UITextField in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

[image: this is what I want]

I want to create button according to user Tap on tableView , I have use this method but it will overlap my Buttons ,means when second button created it also create a button on first button ,how can I acheive this.  Button creation would be one to one not by multiple selection.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

self.searchText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[_sortedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
self.tableView.hidden = YES;

 [_selectednames addObject:_searchText.text];

    [self makeLabelsAndButtons:_selectednames];

   // }

self.searchText.text = nil;

 }


 -(void)makeLabelsAndButtons:(NSMutableArray *)arrButton{

 int y=10;
 int x=10;

for (int i=0; i<[arrButton count]; i++) {
    CGRect screenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth=screenRect.size.width;

  //  [_arrBtnStatus addObject:[NSNumber  numberWithInt:i]];


    NSString *strNames=[arrButton objectAtIndex:i];
   CGSize stringsize=[strNames sizeWithAttributes:
                @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]}];
   UIButton  *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    CGFloat m=x+stringsize.width+30;
    CGFloat n=screenWidth-20;

    if (m<=n) {
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y,stringsize.width,stringsize.height);
        x=x+stringsize.width +10;

    }
    else
    {
        y=y+stringsize.height+10;
        x=20;
        btn.frame=CGRectMake(x, y,stringsize.width,stringsize.height);
        x=x+stringsize.width+10;
    }

    [btn setTitle:arrButton[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.tag=i;
    [btn addTarget:self
            action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

   btn.layer.cornerRadius=10;
   [btn.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    [self.buttonView addSubview:btn];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with your output what you want and what you get .

Comment: Please, provide us more info. Where you wan't to see a new button? Why you need different buttons. A quick draft would be a good idea too.

Comment: I have edited my question with images ....Now suggest something

Comment: Any one please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

Do initialise the selectednames array whenever the cell for row at indexpath runs.i.e initialise the array in this function.In this way it will add only one item according to selected row.
In your code you are adding object to the same array.Thats why it adds previous button also

Comment: [_selectednames addObject:_searchText.text];

Comment: you are adding in this array whenever the user tap on cell.And creating buttons on this basis.So basically you are always adding something in the array.Just initialise this array at the top of your cellforrow code and it will be fine as it will always create a new array whenever the user taps on cell

Comment: you want to create only one button by tapping on cell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130929/discussion-between-waqar-khalid-and-dheeraj).